# When drawing commutative diagrams, how to represent dense embedding?

Tags: notation, convention

I am taking some notes in functional analysis and I would like to represent a "dense embedding" in a commutative diagram. However, I have not found any convention for this. My current drawing is like:

[image]

However, I do not know how to represent "denseness" of the embedding from X to Y.

Do I use thick arrow? Double head? Different Color?

I would love to see if there are any existing conventions.

---

Update: I would like to thank @ac15 for pointing me to a reference where commutative diagrams were drawn with denseness relations. It seems that only a curly arrow denoting embedding is used, and there is no special arrow notation for denseness.

Comment: on $Haus$ at least it would most likely be a double head [ https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Hausdorff+space#dense_subspaces_and_epimorphisms ], but it may depend on the category at hand

Comment: I agree with ac15 that would be tempted to use both a hook and a double head, but ultimately whatever choice of notation you make should be clarified the first time you use it or before